# Different combinations

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following problem :
On a digital watch there are only finitely many different times that can be 
displayed. How many different times can be displayed on a digital watch that 
shows hours, minutes, and seconds and that distinguishes between A.M . and 
P.M.?

I have found 86 400 variations. Would it be correct ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say so:

- $\times 2$ for AM or PM;
- $\times 12$ for the hour display which can take the values $1,2,\ldots,12$.
- $\times 60$ for the minute display, which can take the values $0,1,\ldots,59$.
- $\times 60$ for the second disply, which can take the values $0,1,\ldots,59$.

Giving a total of $2 \times 12 \times 60 \times 60=86400$ possibilities.

This is essentially the number of seconds in a [day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day).

Comment: Ok, I think that's it. thank you!